# Iterating the quasi-triangle inequality.

Tags: normed-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I am attempting Q1 in Tao's [lecture notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes1.pdf) on harmonic analysis.

Let $\|\|$ be a quasi-norm and let $f_n$, $n = 1, 2, . . . , N$ be a sequence of functions obeying the bounds $\|f_n\| \lesssim 2^{-\epsilon n}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Show that $\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^N f_n\| \lesssim_\epsilon 1$.

If $\epsilon > \log_2(C)$ where C is the constant in the quasi-triangle inequality, you can easily just iterate and then apply the given bound term-wise to get a geometric sum. However, I don't see what to do if $\epsilon$ is small.

The notes claim you can use the quasi-triangle inequality to reduce to the case where $\epsilon$ is large but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $\epsilon k > \log_2(C)$, that is $\epsilon k$ is the kind of  large $\epsilon$ we'd like to have. Split the sequence into subsequences such as 
$$
(f_1, f_{1+k}, f_{1+2k}, f_{1+3k}, \dots ) \quad \text{and}\quad 
(f_2, f_{2+k}, f_{2+2k}, f_{2+3k}, \dots) 
$$ 
For each of these subsequences we in effect have $k\epsilon $ in the exponent, so the backward summation works to estimate the sum by $\lesssim 1$. And the number of these subsequences depends only on $\epsilon$ and $C$ (not on $N$), so just add them up and the effect of this summation goes into the implicit constant in the inequality.